# How do I use Url.Route for OData routes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, odata, url-routing

I'm attempting to create an OData function that returns a list of references (id/name values) for multiple resource types.

Each reference will also contain a "ResourceUrl" property, with the relative path to the resource's url.

For instance, this is what I want to see

```
    {
      "id": 4438,
      "name": "Some Dude",
      "resourceUri": "/odata/Users(4438)
    },
```

Current I'm using `Url.Route("odata", new { controller = "users", id = user.Id })` but the result is returning `null`.

Both the controller containing the function and the UsersController inherits from ODataController.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve my problem by slightly modifying the answer from this question: [How to Link to OData Collection in Razor using ASP.NET MVC Web API OData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488574/how-to-link-to-odata-collection-in-razor-using-asp-net-mvc-web-api-odata)

Instead of Url.HttpRouteUrl, I use Url.Route

**Extension Method**

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    private static IODataPathHandler _pathHandler = new DefaultODataPathHandler();

    public static string ODataUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string routeName, params ODataPathSegment[] segments)
    {
        var odataPath = _pathHandler.Link(new ODataPath(segments));
        return urlHelper.Route(routeName, new RouteValueDictionary() { { ODataRouteConstants.ODataPath, odataPath } });
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Url.ODataUrl("odata", new EntitySetPathSegment("Users"), new KeyValuePathSegment(u.UserId.ToString()))
```

Comment: In ASP.NET Core this is properly addressed with library supplied extension methods and related resources. The Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.UrlHelperExtensions class, the CreateODataLink overloaded methods.